# CSS, vertical-align an anchor in table cell

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

I need to align the anchor tag in a table cell to top, the table cell contains a textarea. My code is as below but the anchor tag is align to bottom of the textarea.

```
<style>
td {
  border:#777 1px solid; vertical-align:top;
}

textarea {
  height:100px; width:300px;
}
</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Message:</td>
    <td>
      <textarea></textarea>
      <a href="javascript:" title="Required">*</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How to vertical-align that anchor tag to top of the cell?

[image]

Comment: `table` element *and* CSS or layout? Would you consider using CSS for all of it?

Comment: i already put the 'vertical-align' in css for 'td' tag. as u can see the word 'Message' is on top of the cell. but in the right cell with a textarea, it's not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `Textarea` used to push the near element down to be in same line

```
a {
vertical-align: top;
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yjkSJ/)

Answer (score 2):

Give that anchor a vertical-alignment of top as well:

```
td a {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Message:</td>
<td>
  <textarea></textarea>
 </td>
<td> <a href="javascript:" title="Required">*</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```